# How to preserve symlinks when unpacking tar using maven assembly plugin

Tags: maven, maven-2, maven-3, maven-assembly-plugin

I am writting a maven assembly descriptor and one of the task is to download a tar file, unpack it before creating a final tarball out of many components.

I cant figure out how to preserve symlinks from the tar using the maven assembly plugin. Has anybody seen this issue before?

```
<assembly>
    <id>myassembly</id>
    <formats>
            <format>dir</format>
    </formats>
    <includeBaseDirectory>false</includeBaseDirectory>
    <dependencySets>
            <dependencySet>
                    <useProjectArtifact>false</useProjectArtifact>
                    <outputDirectory>.</outputDirectory>
                    <unpack>true</unpack>
            </dependencySet>
    </dependencySets>

</assembly>
```

Comment: unfortunately there is no possibility to create a sym link via maven-assembly-plugin nor that i know a plugin which is able to do so. May be you can solve that by using groovy plugin or exec-maven-plugin ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Preserving symlinks is not supported in any of the maven plugins at the momenet. I got around this problem by using the maven executor plugin that would execulte a shell script and tar and untar artifacts for me.

Comment: still valid statement?

Comment: @user2124712 version 2.10 supports symlinks

Comment: Maven assembly >= 2.5.4 also supports symlinks (certainly 2.6.0 does) - https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/MASSEMBLY-750

Answer (score 6):

Now everything is becoming better.
I see both maven dependency plugin and assembly plugin correctly supporting symlinks. Following versions and definitions are used:

```
<plugin>
    <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
    <artifactId>maven-dependency-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>2.10</version>
</plugin>
<plugin>
    <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
    <artifactId>maven-assembly-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>2.5.4</version>
</plugin>
```

Comment: I can confirm that maven-dependency-plugin 2.10 works well with zipped symlinks on OSX out of the box. Thank you!

Comment: I am using version 2.6 of the maven-assembly-pluging, but still my symlinks get broken on unpack.  Is there something I am missing?

Comment: If this is unpacking it may be dependency plugin version.

Comment: This does work for me as well . In case you came across any issues where sym links are not persisting, ensure they exist at the time of creation, before packaging, as well as at the time of unpacking/unzipping.