# Create Symlink for dependencies in Maven assembly

Tags: maven, dependencies, maven-assembly-plugin

I have a Maven assembly that after unpacking the tar, creates three directories
each containing a /lib directory. So e.g.

```
folder1/lib
folder2/lib
folder3/lib
```

Currently, I am packing a same .jar in each of these /lib directories. Since this is a waste of space, I was wondering if I could have just one copy of that .jar and create something like a symlink for other two locations that could reference that .jar?

Thanks!

Answer (score 4):

Here is my solution with `maven-antrun-plugin` for very similar situation. Zookeeper dependencies are previously placed into `${basedir}/target/package/lib` by `maven-dependency-plugin`. Now I'm creating symlinks for all libraries into `${basedir}/target/package/lib/zookeeper/lib` which point 2 dirs upper.

```
<plugin>
    <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
    <artifactId>maven-antrun-plugin</artifactId>
    <executions>
        <execution>
            <id>prepare-delivery</id>
            <phase>package</phase>
            <goals>
                <goal>run</goal>
            </goals>
            <configuration>
                <target>
                    <!-- Prepare zookeeper layout. -->
                    <mkdir dir="${basedir}/target/package/lib/zookeeper/lib"/>
                    <apply executable="ln" dir="${basedir}/target/package/lib/zookeeper/lib" relative="true">
                        <arg value="-s"/>
                        <srcfile prefix="../../"/>
                        <targetfile/>
                        <fileset dir="${basedir}/target/package/lib" includes="**"/>
                        <mapper type="identity"/>
                    </apply>
                </target>
            </configuration>
        </execution>
    </executions>
</plugin>
```

Plugin management for `antrun` is set as following:

```
<plugin>
    <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
    <artifactId>maven-antrun-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>1.8</version>
</plugin>
```

Comment: Is it possible to create the sym-link with a different name? In target/dist directory, I have my artifact-version.jar. I need to create a sym-link in target/dist directory with name artifact.jar that points to the artifact-version.jar. Is it possible?

Comment: I do not use maven for already more than 2 years but even on the date of answer it was of course possible. Just check antrun plugin documentation. BTW this task 'apply' used is too universal, it can run almost anything and probably now it can be more elegant. The constant need in such hacks with Maven is a main reason why I have moved from Maven to Gradle.

Comment: Thanks! I found a way using symlink task.

Answer (score 2):

I believe this is unsupported in Maven packaging and assembly.  [Another Stack Overflow question from just a year ago asked the same thing](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17734983/how-to-preserve-symlinks-when-unpacking-tar-using-maven-assembly-plugin) and got the "unsupported" answer.  And there have been two JIRAs on this feature (at least) that have been open for quite some time: [one for the assembly plugin](http://jira.codehaus.org/browse/MDEP-68) and [one for Plexus components](http://jira.codehaus.org/browse/PLXCOMP-64).  I would say this the odds of this ever being directly supported are not good.

Just FYI, if I say "source project," I'll be refering to the project that assembled the tar. If I say "destination project," I'll mean the one unpacking the tar.  This is assuming you have Maven projects on both sides- if that assumption is wrong, you should rely on command line utilities to do the tar-ing or untar-ing for you.

Since it sounds to me like you are unpacking the tar in the context of a Maven build, there are ways of working around this.  As far as I know, the best solution if symlinking is important to you is to use either the [junction plugin](http://pyx4j.com/pyx4j-maven-plugins/maven-junction-plugin/introduction.html), the exec-maven-plugin, or the maven-antrun-plugin.

The junction plugin has the advantage of being portable, even on Windows.  The problem is the project doing the unpacking must have explicit knowledge of the structure of the original structure of the tar, which is generally not desirable as it will now have to be updated should the intended symlinking that is changed.  The plugin also seems to be pretty unmaintained, so there's that.

The exec plugin will allow you to call commandline utilities or scripts to do your linking, but you will have to toy with profiles to get crossplatform capabilities.  The best benefit of doing it this way is that the project doing the unpacking is completely agnostic of the original structure of the tar.  The details of the mechanism are in the question from a year ago that I mentioned above.

For my project, I am probably going to use antrun for Ant's [symlink task](https://ant.apache.org/manual/Tasks/symlink.html)- it is possible to have Ant record all symlinks to a file on the source side, and then package that file along with Maven.  The receiving project can then check for the file and recreate its symlinks. This allows the symlinking intended for the tar distribution to be changed from its source project with no changes on the destination project.  My project only supports OS X and Linux, so this is acceptable- you will need to decide which is best for you.

In either case, you will unfortunately have a situation where the project doing the unpacking must have knowledge about the way the tar was before being packed.

Comment: Maven assembly >= 2.5.4 now also supports symlinks (certainly 2.6.0 does) - https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/MASSEMBLY-750

Answer (score 1):

You can use symlink task/goal of ant-run plugin

```
<plugin>
    <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
    <artifactId>maven-antrun-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>1.8</version>
    <executions>
        <execution>
            <phase>package</phase>
            <configuration>
                <target>
                    <symlink link="folder2/lib/${project.artifactId}-${project.version}.jar"
                             resource="folder1/lib/${project.artifactId}-${project.version}.jar"/>
                    <symlink link="folder3/lib/${project.artifactId}-${project.version}.jar"
                             resource="folder1/lib/${project.artifactId}-${project.version}.jar"/>
                </target>
            </configuration>
            <goals>
                <goal>run</goal>
            </goals>
        </execution>
    </executions>
</plugin>
```

If you want the symlinks to have relative path, you can give relative path in resource like below

```
<plugin>
    <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
    <artifactId>maven-antrun-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>1.8</version>
    <executions>
        <execution>
            <phase>package</phase>
            <configuration>
                <target>
                    <symlink link="folder2/lib/${project.artifactId}-${project.version}.jar"
                             resource="../../folder1/lib/${project.artifactId}-${project.version}.jar"/>
                    <symlink link="folder3/lib/${project.artifactId}-${project.version}.jar"
                             resource="../../folder1/lib/${project.artifactId}-${project.version}.jar"/>
                </target>
            </configuration>
            <goals>
                <goal>run</goal>
            </goals>
        </execution>
    </executions>
</plugin>
```